# XML foreach not printing all

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print all elements inside this XML part with for each loop:

```
<education>
        <institution>Buckinghamshire New University</institution>
        <level>BSc Computing and Web</level>
        <startDate>Start date: 2016-09-01 </startDate>
        <endDate>End date: 2019-06-01 </endDate>
        <subject>Programming Concepts</subject>
        <grade>100%</grade>
        <subject>XML</subject>
        <grade>50%</grade>
        <institution>Grammar School</institution>
        <level>Secondary School</level>
        <startDate>2012-09-01 </startDate>
        <endDate>2016-07-01 </endDate>
        <subject>Physical education and sports</subject>
        <grade>A</grade>
        <subject>Philosophy</subject>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <subject>Math</subject>
        <grade>C</grade>
        <subject>English</subject>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <subject>Croatian</subject>
        <grade>B</grade>
</education>
```

I tried with this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="education">
    <xsl:value-of select="subject"/>;<br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="grade"/>;<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it only shows first occurence like this:

```
Programming Concepts
100%
```

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want to show all subjects in a line, then all grades underneath in a second line? Or so you want to show subject, grade, subject, grade, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I am doing wrong ?

You are doing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="education">
```

and there is only one occurrence of `education` in your input. And since you are apparently using XSLT 1.0, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="subject"/>
```

gets the value of the first subject only. You probably want to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="education/subject">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>;<br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::grade[1]"/>;<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but since you did not post the expected result, it's no more than a guess.

Comment: Thank you very much, very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 there is a detail concerning how `value-of` operates,
about which people keep forgetting:

Even if `select` returned multiple items, `value-of` serves **only the first**
of them and the rest (apparently) "vanishes".

In XSLT 2.0 it was changed in 2 ways:

- `value-of` serves **all** returned items (a more intuitive solution).
- It has an additional, optional `separator` attribute, stating what
  to insert between adjacent items.

But assume that you want to keep with 1.0 version.
If you want to print **all** `subject` and `grade` elements in the
document order, you can do it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="education/subject | education/grade">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>;<br/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I added `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` in the loop to keep
each item in a separate row also in the resulting HTML code,
not only in what will be seen in the browser.